# Can't type <>[]{}'"()` and backspace in vim after :set nopaste

Tags: paste

*This is a re-post from my deleted post at Stack Overflow.*

---

OS: MacOS catalina

Vim version: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1

Problem: Can't type `<>[]{}'"()` and `backspace` in vim after `:set nopaste`. Typing `<>[]{}'"()` in insert mode does nothing and the curser just stays at the same place and so does typing delete button.

Expected Behaviour: Could type `<>[]{}'"()` and perform delete by `backspace` in insert mode.

---

I tried `:set backspace=2` and it didn't wrok. What worked though was `:set paste` but it also disabled ncoc and other functionalities so it was not a solution. I thought it might be that some settings in my vimrc caused the problem but deleting my vimrc was of no avail.

Some conversations that might help figuring out the cause:

1. It only happened after I loaded a session by `source session.vim` and it didn't happened after opening a normal file with `e filename` or from terminal.
2. Under `:set paste` and `:set nopaste`, `ctrl + r` + `backspace` both gave `<BS>`
3. When I did `<tab>`, `paste` gave 8 spaces while `nopaste` 4 spaces.

Any idea about the problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Sorry but I read your question a couple of times now and it's still unclear what the problem is that you're trying to report... Can you please [edit] the question and describe what you're trying to do, what you expected it would happen and what is happening instead? Thanks!

Comment: `:set paste` changes a whole bunch of settings to make pasting from other programs more convenient in certain scenarios; you don't really want to set it normally (and if you do set it, you want to disable it again as soon as you've finished pasting the text). It's not entirely clear to me what problem you were having in the first place? I *think* you thought that `:set paste` would fix a problem? What is that problem?

Comment: @filbranden sorry about the confusion! have added problem and expected behaviour to my question.

Comment: @TommyDew Thanks for trying to clarify! But I still don't understand what seems to be happening... When you type, for example, `[`, what happens, nothing? Did you try to run `vim --clean` to disable plug-ins and customizations from your vimrc to check whether some of them might be causing the problem?

Comment: @filbranden Post updated! After pressing the mentioned keys, nothing would happen and the curser stays at the same place. One thing I realised is that this problem only happens when I load a session.

Comment: I'll try debugging my vimrc later to find out the cause.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes I am in insert mode and I found that it is that coc.nvim setting causes the problem. After I uninstall it and delete the corresponding settings in my vimrc, pressing delete in insert mode gives error message: `unknown function: coc#_insert_key`. Now that I have set everything to default and things got back to normal.

Comment: But once I install `coc.nvim` again, things happened again. Same error `E117:unknown function: coc#_insert_key` when I try to delete or type any key mentioned in the post's title.

Comment: @TommyDew *"coc.nvim setting causes the problem"* Alright, so I think you got your answer to why those keys are not working. Can I suggest that you post a self-answer indicating that uninstalling/disabling/removing coc.nvim fixes the issue? Now if you want help properly getting coc.nvim to work, then I recommend you post a new question about that. Describe what you're doing to set it up and why it's not working for you. (Make sure you describe everything in as much detail as you can!)

Comment: Also consider disabling sessions (especially automatically saving/restoring them) as you work with plug-ins, since sessions may end up interfering with the mappings and settings created by your plug-ins.

Comment: @filbranden is there alternative to sessions if I wanna quickly restore a workspace like in vscode? thanks.

Comment: @TommyDew Sessions are the correct feature for that, but you should beware of saving/restoring them automatically (tends to perpetuate issues, since it keeps recording them and it's hard for you to get rid of the bad settings) and take a look at the options controlling what gets saved (sessionoptions and viewoptions, I think.) I guess my point is, even if you want to use them automatically, make sure all the rest is set up first (plug-ins, etc.) and *then* enable sessions, that way they're not interfering with the plug-in settings.

Comment: @filbranden in fact, it's usually views that are the issues; but sessions can be with the wrong `sessionoptions`. I use the plugin obsession for this, no issues so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it was that the coc.nvim caused the problem.

`:verbose map <BS>` shows my `<BS>` is mapped to `coc#_insert_key('request', 'a-very-long-string')` because of coc.nvim.

I solved my problem by

1. Uninstall coc.nvim
2. `:mapclear | mapclear <buffer> | mapclear! | mapclear! <buffer>` to remove all mappings.

Thanks all!